# Error while updating the recyclerview list?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

I am calling a Interface function through adapter that is launching the dialog box. 
I want to do update the recycler view list based on the how user interact with the dialog box i.e. whether he has press positive button or negative button.

Issue that I am facing:

Approach I have tried, whenever user presses positive or negative button , update the global variable and based on this result performing the operation. **But the issue I am facing is function returning the global value even before the user press ok/cancel button.**

Adopter from where I am calling the function:

```
holder.actionTask.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                    Context mainActivityContext= Constants.getContext();

                    if (action_id.equals("pain"))
                    {

                        if (mainActivityContext!=null && mainActivityContext instanceof MainActivity)
                        {
                            interfaceAdapter=((HealthVitalsFunction) mainActivityContext);
                           interfaceAdapter.openPainRecordDialog(context,dbHelper);

                            Toast.makeText(context,"Pain "+Boolean.toString(Constant.taskdone), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                     }
        }
}
```

openPainRecordDialog function:

```
@Override
    public boolean openPainRecordDialog(final Context context, final DbHelper dbHelper) {


        alertDialogBuilder
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("ADD", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            **Constants.taskDone=true;**
                })
                .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Constants.taskDone=false;
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        alertDialog.show();

       return Constants.taskDone;

    }
```

Global Variable:

```
public class Constants {
          public static boolean taskDone;
}
```

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: I have added the code @SurajRao

Comment: What kind of global variable you use in apater ? show us code

Comment: @sushantgosavi I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Default value for boolean is false 
so even if you not assign value it return false

you can do like use false for cancel and just Update list like

create method inside Adapter class

```
public void update(ArrayList<Model> modelList){
    adapterModelList.clear(); 
    for (Product model: modelList) {
        adapterModelList.add(model); 
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Call it like

```
((MyRecyclerAdapter)recyclerView.getAdapter()).update(modelList);
```

Comment: Where should I call update method? in adapter? means how.  my adapter and recyclerview is defined in calling adapter activity

Comment: if you want to call from inside adapter than just  call it like       update(modelList)     


if you want to call from activity or fragment that create adpter instance 
than call it like  
((MyRecyclerAdapter)recyclerView.getAdapter()).update(modelList);

Comment: I am calling the  update(modelList) wherever list is updating. Is there any other alternate to call the function inside adapter. Second point this function is called only when I am scrolling the recyclerview.

Comment: I have call the function through the calling activity but it don't work.